# $A \Rightarrow B$ where $A = $"$f$ is continuous, maps saturated open sets to open sets", $B=$"$f$ is a quotient map" may be false.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f:X \to Y.$ Let $A$ be the assertion $f$ is continuous and maps saturated open sets to open sets, let $B$ be the assertion $f$ is a quotient map. I am struggling to prove $A \Leftrightarrow B,$ which was supposedly "proven" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919672/equivalent-definition-of-a-quotient-map).

My proof of $B \Rightarrow A$ is the same as the given proofs, and my proof of $A \Rightarrow B$ proceeds along the same lines until I get to the statement $f(f^{-1}(U)) = U.$ This is false because we do not know $f$ is surjective. All we know is that $f(f^{-1}(U)) \subseteq U.$ Did the book forget to mention surjectivity in the "is equivalent to..." discussion?

Comment: The entire discussion there is about surjective maps. That is stated explicitly in the definitions of *quotient map* and *saturated with respect to a (surjective) map*, and in that context it should be clear that the final sentence in the extract refers to a surjective map $p:X\to Y$. The author didn’t forget to mention it, but rather assumed that the reader would recognize that it was being assumed throughout that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of $f(f^{-1}(U)) = U$ is the implication $1 \Rightarrow 2$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2466680). And then you get surjectivity from $f(f^{-1}(Y)) = Y,$ completing the proof of $f$ being a quotient map.

Answer (score 0):

The preamble of this discussion by Munkres (I assume that's what you're talking about, as you link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2919672)) assumes that the map $p: X \to Y$ is surjective. So that's assumed throughout this paragraph and "$p$ quotient" $\iff$ $p$ continuous and maps "saturated open sets to open sets" is under this assumption.

So yes, it's not *explicitly* mentioned in a theorem, but it *is* part of the discussion. We never talk about quotient maps and the like for non-surjective functions anyway.

Munkres in fact proved (implicitly, he doesn't give it a number as he doesn't need it later)

Let $p:X \to Y$ be a surjective function. Then TFAE:

1. $p$ is quotient.
2. $p$ is continuous and for every saturated open set $O$ in $X$, $p[O]$ is open in $Y$.